# jquery global variable with value window.getSelection() becomes empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

In one function want to set variable to be able to use in other functions.
Value of the variable is `window.getSelection()`

What i did:

1) selected some text inside `div contenteditable`

2) clicked on `class="fa-link"`. Starts code that assigns value of `window.getSelection()` to variable `global_variable`

3) click anywhere else in page, for example in `id="ahref_name"`. Value of `global_variable` becomes empty.

Why `global_variable` becomes empty? I did not started code that gives value to `global_variable`. So `global_variable` must keep value... like `some_test_var`.

Placed code here https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/565926/

And here is the code:

Html

```
<div contenteditable>To select something</div>

<button class="fa-link">fa-link</button>

<div id="contenteditable_menu_ahref" style="display:none" >
    <input type="text" id="ahref_name" placeholder="Ahref name" />
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var global_variable = '';
var some_test_var = '';

$(document).on('click', '.fa-link', function(){

    console.log ('fa-link clicked');

    $("#contenteditable_menu_ahref").css("display", "block");

    if (window.getSelection) {

        global_variable = window.getSelection();
        console.log( 'global_variable 01 ' + global_variable );

        some_test_var = 'some test var';

        $("#ahref_name").val(global_variable);

    } 

});



$(document).click(function() {
    console.log( "global_variable 02 " + global_variable + ' / some_test_var ' + some_test_var );
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: `window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents();`. The issue is that you are receiving an object and that object is updated every time you select a different part of the DOM. By calling `getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents()` you'll store a **copy** of that selection in you variable.

Comment: In such a way var value is retained. But i get `[object DocumentFragment]`. Must get string from it ... will try to find a way how to get string... `Range.toString()`?

Comment: no, seems need to use `new XMLSerializer().serializeToString()`

Comment: Yo need to use a serializer. Another approach (I don't like it) is to create a new element, insert the content that you copied before and then get the innerHTML of that new element: 
`var content = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents();
var span = document.createElement('SPAN');
span.appendChild(content);
var htmlContent = span.innerHTML;`

Answer (score 1):

The object is replaced when you click on the button. So instead of click, add a mouseup event on selection and store the selected value in the global variable

```
  $("#contenteditable_menu_ahref").mouseup( function(){
           if (window.getSelection) {

               global_variable = window.getSelection();
           }

    });

$(document).on('click', '.fa-link', function(){

    console.log ('fa-link clicked',global_variable);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that:

```
   if (window.getSelection)
```

will also return true because it check that a function called 'window.getSelection' exists (which it does in all modern browsers.

You should simply call:

```
   if (window.getSelection.toString())
```

That will only report true if selection is non-empty.